# OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS: Importing .OBJ files from zBrush export without normals

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

Let me preface this by saying I’m fairly new at OpenGL ES and OpenGL in general.

I’ve got a model object that our 3D guy exported from zBrush. It doesn’t have any normals in the `.obj` file, and I *think* that’s what’s causing this behavior. I’m using [obj2opengl](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/) to create a `.h` file containing the vertices and texture coordinates, then importing those and rendering. Here’s what the import looks like:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &mushroomVertexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mushroomVertexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mushroom01b_LowVerts), mushroom01b_LowVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &mushroomTextureBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mushroomTextureBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mushroom01b_LowTexCoords), mushroom01b_LowTexCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

When it’s time to draw the object, here’s the code I’m using:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mushroomVertexBufferID);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 3, NULL);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mushroomTextureBufferID);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, NULL);

self.effect.texture2d0.name = _mushroomTextureInfo.name;
self.effect.texture2d0.target = _mushroomTextureInfo.target;

[self.effect prepareToDraw];

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mushroom01b_LowNumVerts);
```

This works, and for models where I’ve opened them in Blender, fixed the normals, and re-exported as OBJ with normals (adding code above for a third array buffer), it looks pretty good. But if I don’t modify the exported-from-zBrush OBJ at all, here’s what I get:

[image: Messed up normals]

Now, this is with face culling enabled with `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);`. If I don’t enable it, the model seems to be rendering inside-out.

Clearly the zBrush export is messed up somehow. My question is how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model isn't triangulated. Have your artist check that box on the output.

I went and looked into the script file for you.

Assuming the quad is

```
a -- c
|    |
|    |
b -- d
```

In the .pl you'll find

## rectangle => second triangle

```
    if($5 != "")
    {
        @d = split('/', $5);
        $va_idx[$numFaces] = $a[0]-1;
        $ta_idx[$numFaces] = $a[1]-1;
        $na_idx[$numFaces] = $a[2]-1;

        $vb_idx[$numFaces] = $d[0]-1;
        $tb_idx[$numFaces] = $d[1]-1;
        $nb_idx[$numFaces] = $d[2]-1;

        $vc_idx[$numFaces] = $c[0]-1;
        $tc_idx[$numFaces] = $c[1]-1;
        $nc_idx[$numFaces] = $c[2]-1;

        $face_line[$numFaces] = $line;

        $numFaces++;
    }
```

Try reordering to this to see if the second triangle's winding order needs to be reversed

## rectangle => second triangle

```
    if($5 != "")
    {
        @d = split('/', $5);
        $va_idx[$numFaces] = $a[0]-1;
        $ta_idx[$numFaces] = $a[1]-1;
        $na_idx[$numFaces] = $a[2]-1;

                    $vb_idx[$numFaces] = $c[0]-1;
        $tb_idx[$numFaces] = $c[1]-1;
        $nb_idx[$numFaces] = $c[2]-1;

        $vc_idx[$numFaces] = $d[0]-1;
        $tc_idx[$numFaces] = $d[1]-1;
        $nc_idx[$numFaces] = $d[2]-1;



        $face_line[$numFaces] = $line;

        $numFaces++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a request in with them to check that box and I’ll update here how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Try change culling from clockwise to counterclockwise, if your tool respects orientation in obj and zBrush export respects it this might help.

Comment: Sounds likely. That looks way to regular to be just random.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using `glFrontFace(GL_CCW);` but it renders similarly to the image.